# Is any special value "all the file" for CXSourceRange in Clang?

Tags: clang

I want to tokenize cpp file using clang:

```
// range = all the file
CXSourceLocation beginning = clang_getLocationForOffset(TU, file, 0);
CXSourceLocation end = clang_getLocationForOffset(TU, file, 53); // TODO : set actual file length
CXSourceRange range = clang_getRange(beginning, end);

clang_tokenize(TU, range, &tokens, &numTokens);
```

The code works and i can see actual tokens.

I need to set CXSourceRange for this. In my case it will be always "all the file" from beginning to the end. Is there any special value meaning "all the file"? Otherwise i have to get file size or hardcode any actual value as in example above.

Comment: if i specify max(int) or any big value that is larger then filesize clang_tokenize returns 0 tokens meaning it's incorrect range

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

`CXSourceRange range = clang_getCursorExtent(clang_getTranslationUnitCursor(TU));`

to get a range that covers the entire translation unit. See [clang_getTranslationUnitCursor(...)](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CURSOR__MANIP.html#gaec6e69127920785e74e4a517423f4391) and [clang_getCursorExtent(...)](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CURSOR__SOURCE.html#ga79f6544534ab73c78a8494c4c0bc2840).

E.g. this program tokenizes a file given as an argument:

```c++
#include <clang-c/Index.h>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: tokenize <file>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    CXIndex index = clang_createIndex(0, 0);
    CXTranslationUnit TU = clang_parseTranslationUnit(index, 0, argv, argc, 0, 0, CXTranslationUnit_None);
    CXSourceRange range = clang_getCursorExtent(clang_getTranslationUnitCursor(TU));

    // Tokenize.
    CXToken *tokens;
    unsigned int numTokens;
    clang_tokenize(TU, range, &tokens, &numTokens);

    for (int i = 0; i < numTokens; ++i) {
        CXToken token = tokens[i];
        switch (clang_getTokenKind(token)) {
            case CXToken_Punctuation:
                std::cout << "CXToken_Punctuation" << std::endl;
                break;
            case CXToken_Keyword:
                std::cout << "CXToken_Keyword" << std::endl;
                break;
            case CXToken_Identifier:
                std::cout << "CXToken_Identifier" << std::endl;
                break;
            case CXToken_Literal:
                std::cout << "CXToken_Literal" << std::endl;
                break;
            case CXToken_Comment:
                std::cout << "CXToken_Comment" << std::endl;
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "Unknown" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    clang_disposeTokens(TU, tokens, numTokens);
    clang_disposeTranslationUnit(TU);
    clang_disposeIndex(index);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any line number larger than the file size will work.

```
CXSourceLocation end = clang_getLocationForOffset(TU, file, std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max(), 1);
```